# Difference between flat and hierarchical fixtures in CommCare

Tags: commcare

What’s the difference between hierarchical location fixture and flat location fixture in CommCare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hierarchical location fixture is officially deprecated, and is only available to older projects which were already using it.  The flat fixture is easier to reference in your application and automatically makes use of some optimizations on the phone to make it faster.

[This](https://wiki.commcarehq.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40305423) is a page on how to migrate from the hierarchical to the flat fixture.

[This](https://wiki.commcarehq.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38276915) is a page on how to reference the flat fixture in your application.